# Измерение кол-ва памяти, необходимой для выполнения программы

Tags: python, память, ram

Возможно ли измерить кол-во памяти, необходимой для выполнения программы? Сама программа с рекурсивной функцией.

Задача, для которой написан код:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код решения:

```
from functools import lru_cache
from sys import setrecursionlimit

sys.setrecursionlimit(500000000)
@lru_cache(maxsize=None)

def F(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    if n % 2 != 0:
        return F(n - 1) +  1
    if n > 0 and(n % 2 == 0):
        return F(n/2)

x = 0
for i in range(1, 1000000000):
    if F(i) > 3:
        x += 1
print(x)
```

Моих 32гб не хватает для подсчета, но и цели нет решить эту задачу с помощью кода (есть аналитический способ).
Просто хотелось бы узнать, есть ли какие-либо способы для вычисление количество памяти, необходимой программе.

Comment: Я понимаю, что вам интересно знать сколько надо памяти, чтобы решить данную задачу. Но это вам не пригодиться. Но так то вам это в жизни навряд ли пригодиться, д и это можно сделать и на более слабом компьютере, чем у вас, просто будет код выполняться ооочень долго, проверял, когда к ЕГЭ готовился. Данные задачи (с таким размером) решаются в одну минуту на листочке, так что лучше не забивайте голову этим вопросом, хотя ответ я вам уже дал на него, что хватит и 16 гб, но времени убьете много очень

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/monitoring-memory-usage-of-a-running-python-program/

Comment: Собственно, рекурсия то у вас не глубокая, на самом деле больше чем `20_000` рекурсию вообще ставить без толку, там интерпретатор питона всё-равно упадёт, сколько ни ставь. А память у вас на кэш расходуется, если поставите хотя бы `10_000_000` ограничение на кэш, то этот код уже не упадёт. Больше всё-равно особо смыла нет и это же `LRU` кэш, он подстраивается, там всё-равно миссов полно выходит, сколько ни ставь размер, так что ограничить его очень даже имеет смысл.